# R: Markdown or HTML markup in `gtsummary` tables

Tags: r, r-markdown, gtsummary, gt

I have a table with variable names usually spelt with superscript or subscript numbers. I'm using R package `{gtsummary}` to automatically create the table from select columns of a data frame/tibble.

Say this is the tibble:

```
library(nycflights13)

lm_1 <- lm(arr_delay ~ air_time, flights)

tbl_1 <- tbl_regression(lm_1, exponentiate = F,
                        label = list(
                            air_time ~ "Air Time"
                        )) %>% 
    add_glance_source_note(include = c('r.squared'))

tbl_1
```

… but I need to write this as Air<sup>time</sup> (HTML `Air<sup>time</sup>` or Markdown `Air~time~`).

In `{gtsummary}`, specifying the `label` argument in HTML or Markdown doesn't work for me:

```
tbl_1 <- tbl_regression(lm_1, exponentiate = F,
                        label = list(
                            air_time ~ "Air<sup>time</sup>",
                            sched_dep_time ~ "Departure^time^"
                        )) %>% 
    add_glance_source_note(include = c('r.squared'))
```

[image: Table: not working for me]

I've tried wrapping the strings in `gt::html()` or `gt::md()` but it didn't change anything:

```
tbl_1 <- tbl_regression(lm_1, exponentiate = F,
                        label = list(
                            air_time ~ html("Air<sup>time</sup>"),
                            sched_dep_time ~ md("Departure^time^")
                        )) %>% 
    add_glance_source_note(include = c('r.squared'))
```

Would it be possible to use HTML and/or Markdown in `gtsummary` tables? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To 100% honest, I don't know why this solution works...but it does!  The {gt} package has a function called `fmt_markdown()` that is meant to convert markdown syntax to the specified output type. BUT in your example, the markdown superscript is not recognized (more on why here https://github.com/rstudio/gt/issues/129#issuecomment-663753251). BUUUUT, when I apply that function to your HTML tag superscripts, they are recognized and you get the output you're looking for.

```r
library(gtsummary)
library(nycflights13)

lm_1 <- lm(arr_delay ~ air_time + sched_dep_time , flights)

tbl_regression(lm_1, 
               label = list(air_time ~ "Air<sup>time</sup>",
                            sched_dep_time ~ "Departure<sup>time</sup>")) %>% 
  add_glance_source_note(include = 'r.squared') %>%
  as_gt() %>%
  gt::fmt_markdown(columns = vars(label))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @daniel (I can not get user tagging to work)  thanks for the great package and for this trick, it's very useful.

I wonder if you have put any thought into the stability of this "hack". I am hoping to build something similar to this into an automation pipeline and would like to know if this is likely to still work in the future. 

It would be great to have the choice to render cell contents based on raw md/html, which this allows for (I am actually using: `tab %>% gt::fmt(columns = everything(), fns = function(x) x)` which works perfectly.

Thanks!

Comment: For a definitive answer, I would post an issue to the gt GitHub page.

I don't see why it wouldn't work into the future